# How can I save ALL sheets in a LibreOffice Calc Spreadsheet from a command-line Python script

Tags: python, csv, libreoffice

I am trying out a command-line program to export the sheets (four in all) from a LibreOffice ODS spreadsheet file as CSV.
I am working with what is basically PyODConverter.py at https://github.com/mirkonasato/pyodconverter.

The problem I am confronted with is, to save /all/ four of the sheets in the file (the current approach is to save them in a separate file for each sheet).

Disclaimer: I don't feel overly confident in programming in Python (yet). Anyway, in the aforementioned python script, at the end of the convert function, I have added this:

```
    try:
        oSheets = document.Sheets
        for i in range( oSheets.Count ):
            sheet = oSheets.getByIndex( i )
            document.CurrentController.setActiveSheet( sheet )
            outputUrl = self._toFileUrl( sheet.Name + ".csv" )
            print sheet.Name + " " + outputUrl
            document.storeToURL( outputUrl, self._toProperties( storeProperties ) )
    finally:
        document.close(True)
```

However, what this does is save the currently active sheet four times.  The odd thing is that this fragment does correctly 'visit' all sheets (their names are reported in succession), but at the point when they are saved, always the same sheet is saved.  So I end up with four identical CSV files.

The intended result has been so evasive that I'm beginning to think it can't be done.

(side note on operating environment: I have an LibreOffice listener running, so all is set up to go, and the script does in fact function, only the result is not as expected).
Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have all the code here but if you're using pyodconverter as a framework the problem might be the line:

```
     loadProperties = { "Hidden": True }
```

When the Hidden property is set the setActiveSheet method doesn't work. Try it without setting Hidden to true.